# How to increase a DC nominal voltage or switch for 12 V feedback with a 60 mV to 150 mV activation DC voltage?

Tags: voltage-regulator, comparator, npn, feedback, switching-regulator

Currently doing a project whereby a 12 V DC signal is sent from a secondary device with a voltage switch designed to then allow the 12 V signal to be returned activating the secondary device. Activation of the secondary device is dependent on a welder being used. DC voltages (60 mV - 150 mV) are measured at the earth's ground clamp and then these voltages would then activate the switch thus returning the 12 V DC voltage. So far I've modelled an NPN switch, however I need to either increase the voltage (it's DC) or use a comparator to provide either 0 V or 1 V to the NPN switch.

[image: image of NPN switch]

I'm not a novice but it's been a while since I did some op amp work and any circuit examples would be great.

Comment: i tried modelling it on lt spice but was unable to get it to work